# How to Produce a file with Results with Text Mining using K Means Clustering in R

Tags: r, text, cluster-analysis, mining

I have a set of data which has a text field which I am trying to automatically label as relevant or not based on the text field. I have already manually labelled the data but am trying to compare the automatic labels to the manual labels to calculate the accuracy of the automatic labelling. I am using K Means clustering to cluster the data into 2 clusters. Where I am struggling is creating a csv file with my original data and the clusters they are in. The idea is that I will have a csv file showing which row is in which cluster so I can look at which label that the majority of each cluster has and assign that label to each row in that cluster. Then I can use that for further analysis.

This is an example of the data I have (much simplified). Relevance is my manual labels.

```
Id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

Relevance <- c("Relevant", "Not Relevant", "Relevant", "Relevant", "Relevant", "Not Relevant", "Not Relevant", "Not Relevant", "Relevant", "Relevant")

Text <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Fish", "Cow", "Horse", "Fox", "Rat", "Bird", "Tiger", "Elephant")

Data <- cbind(Id, Relevance, Text)
```

This is the code I have for creating the clusters:

```
Data<- read.csv("Desktop\\Data.csv", header=TRUE)
#creating a corpus using the text field of my data
corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(Data$text))

#I did some pre-processing of the texts here eg remove punctuation

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Data)
newdtm <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.99)

#perform the k means clustering
d <- dist(t(newdtm), method="euclidian")
kfit<-kmeans(d, 2)
```

So how do I create a csv file which shows my original data with an additional column showing the cluster each row is in?

The output I am looking for would look like the result of this:

```
Id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
Relevance <- c("Relevant", "Not Relevant", "Relevant", "Relevant", "Relevant", "Not Relevant", "Not Relevant", "Not Relevant", "Relevant", "Relevant")
Text <- c("Cat", "Dog", "Fish", "Cow", "Horse", "Fox", "Rat", "Bird", "Tiger", "Elephant")
Cluster <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1)

cbind(Id, Relevance, Text, Cluster)
```

Comment: We can't help you without a reproducible example: a sample of the data you're trying to save (never mind all the preprocessing which is irrelevant to your problem), and the desired output/result.

Comment: I have updated it to include a small sample of the data I have and the output I would like.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cluster such data with k-means.

### Use k-means on *continuous* numerical attributes only

As the name suggests, the method requires the *mean* to make sense on the data. But what is the mean of "cat" and "dog"?

Document-term-matrix only work on *loooooong* text. As a rule of thumb, 100 words per text is the minimum.

In your example, every record is *completely* dissimilar from ever other record. Look at your matrix, you are attempting to "cluster" this data:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Unsurprisingly, the results are pretty much random on such data. Also, you are using k-means worng - it uses the raw data matrix, not a distance matrix.